# How do I read a MS Power Automate data table in Python?

Tags: python, power-automate-desktop

I am wondering how to read the format of a MS power automate data table and convert it into a an array in python so that i can use it. It would have to solve the problem of spaces, maybe by turning them into underscores and also be able to handle multiple values with the same name.

Comment: Is this PAD(PowerAutomate Desktop) because it sounds like it. If so, please change the tag.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i changed the tag